# Como guardar e recuperar vários retornos de uma requisição AJAX em loop?

Tags: php, javascript, mysql, ajax

Senhores, boa noite. Estou tentando realizar a seguinte tarefa, estou enviando via AJAX a uma outra página 3 cep's, ao chegar lá eu dou apenas um echo do cep enviado pra saber que chegou, esse echo entra na verificação de sucesso aonde eu testo a validade, ou seja, diferente de vazio e entra a próxima ação. Quando dou apenas um alert(data) ele mostra os ceps um de cada vez conforme loop, porém se eu digo pra realizar um incremento a cada vez e já fora do loop eu dou um alert de n então o alert resulta em 0 (zero).

Me desculpem a ignorância caso a pergunta seja boba ou eu que esteja cometendo algum erro trivial.

O intuito desse teste é que a ideia é chegar na seguinte solução, um db que contem dados precisa receber dados do csv desde que esses dados já não existam no banco, logo pensei na seguinte solução, a a pagina um carrega o csv, chama o ajax, o ajax chama a pagina php responsável pela verificação e insert e sempre que esta retornar 1 (um) o ajax faz um incremento, por que isso, pra poder informar ao usuário que de X registros importados N foram inseridos.

```
function testeAjax() {

var cep = ['cep 01', 'cep 02','cep 03'];
var n = 0;
for(var c=0 ; c < cep.length ; c++){

    jQuery.ajax({
        type: "POST",
        url: "./_inc/controler/uploadArquivosControle.php",
        data: { acao:'insertUpdate', cep: cep[c] },
        success: function( data ){

            if(data!==''){
                n++;
            }

        }

    });

}
alert(n);
}

<?php
$acao = $_REQUEST['acao'];

$dao = new UploadArquivosDAO();

switch ($acao) :
    case 'insertUpdate':

        $cep      = addslashes($_POST['cep']);
        echo $cep;
    break;
endswitch;
```

Comment: O problema é que quando chega na linha `alert(n);` o Ajax ainda não foi processado porque ele é assíncrono.

Comment: Imagine a situação comparativa em que os Ajax sejam 3 emails que vc manda para um amigo e espera uma resposta de cada mensagem enviada. As respostas não vêem no mesmo momento e ao chegar na linha do alert vc não teve nenhuma resposta ainda. Ou seja, seu amigo ainda vai ter que abrir o email dele, ler a mensagem e responder, e isso não acontece na mesma hora que vc mandou as mensagens.

Answer (score 0):

Como havia comentado, o Ajax é assíncrono. O código dentro do `for` é chamado mas o `alert` que vem logo depois é executado imediatamente antes do Ajax dar resposta.

Neste caso o correto seria usar a função de forma recursiva e ir chamando cada Ajax após o anterior retornar a requisição no `success`. Como no exemplo você deseja fazer 3 requisições Ajax (tamanho da array `cep`), faça um `if` verificando se a variável que conta o número de requisições é menor que o tamanho da array: se for menor, você faz uma nova requisição; se não, dispara o alert.

Crie a variável que conta as requisições fora da função usando um nome específico para o caso para não conflitar com outras possíveis variáveis que vier a usar (no caso usei `num_cep`). Essa variável começa com o valor `0`. A cada `success` você irá incrementar a variável e chamar novamente a função. Quando o valor da variável for igual ao número de itens da array `cep`, o `if` cairá no `else` disparando o alert com o número de requisições efetuadas que retornaram `!== ''` na variável `inseriu`:

```
var num_cep = 0;
var inseriu = 0;
function testeAjax() {

   var cep = ['cep 01', 'cep 02','cep 03'];
   var cep_length = cep.length;

   if(num_cep < cep_length){

       jQuery.ajax({
           type: "POST",
           url: "./_inc/controler/uploadArquivosControle.php",
           data: { acao:'insertUpdate', cep: cep[num_cep] },
           success: function( data ){
               if(data!==''){
                   inseriu++;
               }
               num_cep++;
               testeAjax();

           }

       });

   }else{
      alert(inseriu);
      // reseta as variáveis
      num_cep = 0;
      inseriu = 0;

   }
}
```